# Lua - unpack then pack an array

Tags: lua

If I unpack then pack an array:

```
arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
arr = table.pack(table.unpack(arr))
```

Will I guarantee that the resulting `arr` is the same as the initial `arr`?

In the [documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.pack) it states:

> Note that the resulting table may not be a sequence.

What does this mean?

Comment: if `arr` was a sequence (no `nil`s inside) and is not too long (limit is 8000 elements for LuajIT), then `pack(unpack(arr))` will be a sequence too.

Comment: If you care about a table having a sequence or not, perhaps it best not to a term like "array", roughly corresponds to a table with or without a sequence and without other fields of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you cite is talking about nils as in
`table.pack(1,nil,3)`.

Your table is a sequence and so `table.unpack(arr)` outputs no nils and `table.pack(table.unpack(arr))` is a sequence.

However, `table.pack(table.unpack(arr))` differs from the original `arr` because it contains a field `n` with value 5. This is the only difference.

Comment: Also note, `{table.unpack(arr)}` is faster, and works for the most part identically.